# When Drag/Drop a file inside a document library, error "A file with the name XXXX.oft already exists. It was last modified"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, versioning, drag-and-drop

We have sharepoint 2013 on-premises, and inside a team site we have a document library which does not have versioning enabled, as follow:-

[image]

now i uploaded a file named `n1.oft` using the "upload" option. and the file got added successfully. then i edited the `n1.oft` locally inside my PC, and i drag/drop the updated file inside the document library, where i got this message >> and then i clicked on "Replace It" , as follow:-

[image]

so i thought that the old file will get replaced by the dragged file, but instead i got this error:-

> A file with the name n1.oft already exists. It was last modified

as follow:-

[image]

so i am not sure why the "Replace It" option when doing a drag/drop of existing file is not working in our case.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a test in my SharePoint 2013 with latest cu and i cannot reproduce your issue.

For your issue, i suggest you doing the following:

Check whether the issue exists in all document library. Create a new library and check whether the issue exists in new library.

Check whether the issue exists in all documents. Try to upload other document in the issue library, and compare the results.